# «На перемене» обособляется запятой?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, спп, смысл

«Директор хотел бы увидеть, как вы танцуете вальс с одноклассниками на перемене».
«На перемене» обособляется запятой?

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы правильно записать это предложение, нужно знать, что имеется в виду, а именно, к чему относится ***на перемене***.

1. *Директор хотел бы увидеть, как вы **танцуете** вальс с одноклассниками **на перемене***.

Такая пунктуация возможна, если речь идёт о вальсе, который танцуют на перемене, и директор хочет это увидеть. С перестановкой слов смысл более понятен:
*Директор хотел бы увидеть, как вы **на перемене танцуете** вальс с одноклассниками*.

2. *Директор **хотел бы увидеть**, как вы танцуете вальс с одноклассниками, **на перемене***.

Эта запись говорит о том, что директор хочет увидеть вальс на перемене.
Запятая закрывает придаточное изъяснительное предложение. При перестройке получается так:
*На перемене директор хотел бы увидеть, как вы танцуете вальс с одноклассниками.*

Comment: А разве есть какой-то особенный вальс, который танцуют на перемене? И семантика второго примера не отличается от первого , с запятой и без. Здесь нет добавочного сообщения.

Comment: @Серж Это не какой-то особенный вальс, а просто вальс, который танцуют / будут танцевать на перемене. Это менее вероятный вариант, но именно он вытекает из пунктуации без запятой. Второй вариант более вероятен: директор хочет увидеть вальс на перемене. Не "переменный" вальс, а просто вальс, и именно на перемене он хочет его лицезреть.

Comment: Не надо разделять глаголом "на перемене" и "увидеть". А то будто на перемене хотел бы.

Answer (score 1):

не думаю, что нужна запятая, разве что интонационная.

Сижу на уроке, танцую на перемене, стою на часах. НА - обычный предлог употребляемый к временному промежутку. На перемене - обстоятельство времени, ничего сверх.

Интонационная запятая, если, скажем:

Директор хотел бы увидеть, как вы танцуете вальс с одноклассниками, (но) на перемене. Когда есть интонационное подчеркивание, что обязательно на перемене, а мол не на уроке или после уроков, может прямо на следующей перемене. Но это скорее исключение, чем правило.

С интонационной запятой не все согласны) так что лучше не обособлять.

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147421/discussion-on-answer-by-----); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 1):

*Директор хотел бы увИдеть, как вы танцуете вальс с одноклАссниками, //  **на перемЕне.***

Обособляется обстоятельство **со значением времени.** В устной речи делается **пауза**. (В предложении расставлены ударения и обозначена пауза.)

**Пояснение**

**Смысл** сообщения такой:  *Директор хотел бы увидеть, как вы танцуете вальс с одноклассниками. Это возможно на перемене.*

В разговорной речи  это обстоятельство с **уточняющим** значением. Оно  в краткой форме выражает содержание **целого предложения** и поэтому обособляется. Можно сказать, что это "разговорная парцелляция", обозначенная запятой.

Comment: Зачем обособлять? Парцелляция худ. прием. У нас не такое предложение Не думаю, что в разговорной речи кто-то будет делать такие паузы. Это обычное предложение с обстоятельством времени. И никакие запятые тут не нужны.

Answer (score 0):

Второй ответ

***Директор хотел бы увидеть,  // как вы танцуете вальс  / с одноклассниками на перемене.***

1. Почему **лично мне** предложение без обособления кажется **некорректным**? Можно подумать, что школьники  **часто** (если не каждый день) на переменах танцуют вальс, чтобы отдохнуть или выполнить задание для урока танцев. Где? В актовом зале или, может, прямо в коридоре. И директора заинтересовало, как это выглядит.
2. **Я слышу такой подтекст**, но не настаиваю на том, чтобы все его слышали. Кроме того, **структура** предложения кажется мне неоправданно усложненной для разговорной фразы. Поэтому можно сделать вывод: "на перемене" – это уже **следующее** сообщение.
3. Но если предложение считать все-таки корректным, то обосновать обособление обстоятельства сложно. **Цитата**: *Да, предложение абсолютно **корректно**. Это обычное предложение с обстоятельством времени. И никакие запятые тут **не нужны**.*
4. А вот при обособлении обстоятельства мы получаем запись разговорной речи для конкретной ситуации: ***Директор хотел бы увидеть, // как вы танцуете вальс с одноклассниками, // на перемене.***

**Вывод.** Это скорее **уточнение**, которое следует обозначить как запятой на письме, так и паузой в устной речи.

Comment: Вот так надо обосновывать свою позицию. Умеете же! А обычно образная ерунда.

Comment: С запятой два варианта (присоединение и часть главного предложения). Это не есть хорошо.